# GCP GKE - FailedPrecondition - Operation is currently deleting a node pool for cluster

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

While trying to create or delete multiple nodepools in the [GKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform#Compute) cluster, I'm getting the below error.

The Go [GCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) SDK on create or delete nodepool.

```
rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = Operation operation-XXXX is currently deleting a node pool for cluster my-cluster. Please wait and try again once it is done.
```

Is there a specific limitation with the GKE cluster that needs to be revoked?

Comment: can you give more detailed code ? I suspect sequential operations while the previous operation is not finished. May be wait for previous node pool completed before doing the next one.

Comment: It's simple goland SDK requesting for creating new nodepool, running in cloud function. Each code execution is in isolation. It is not in sequence from code side. GCP GKE must be maintaining the sequence of requests and throwing above error.